# Quadratics with Integer Intercepts and Extrema

Tags: quadratics, parametrization

I'm a math teacher and was creating an exam for my Algebra 1 students when I tried picking an equation that had integer Intercepts (both x- and y-), as well as extrema. I wanted to do so because I figured integer values would be most easily identifiable and comfortable for my students.

But that got me wondering... How would one guarantee that a given quadratic in standard form meets those three constraints?

I've got some ideas, but curious to know of other approaches that might be out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=a(x-r)(x-s)$, where $a,r,s$ are integers and $a\ne 0$.

The vertex has $x$-coordinate ${\Large{\frac{r+s}{2}}}\!$,$\;$so the only additional condition you need is for $r+s$ to be even.

For example, using $a,r,s=1,3,-5$, you get
$$f(x)=1(x-3)(x+5)=x^2+2x-15$$
which has $x$-intercepts $(3,0),(-5,0)$,$\;y$-intecept $(0,-15)$, and vertex $(-1,-16)$.

Comment: Thank you quasi! This is definitely an interesting approach. I started with standard form and instead arrived at this procedure. (1) Pick an even value for b. (2) List the values of a for which 2a is a factor of b. (3) For each value of a, find the value of c that solves the equation -2=ac/(b^2). This produces a quadratic that meets the desired criteria. Take for example, b = 6. Therefore, a = 1 or a = 3. If a = 1, c = -72. If  a = 3, c = -24. Thus, (x^2)+6x-72 and 3(x^2)+6x-24 both meet the criteria described. Let me know what you think!

Comment: @NC1208: Your method works, but it doesn't yield all qualifying quadratics. For example, using $a=1,b=2$, your method gives $c=-8$, which works, but for $a=1,b=2$, there are infinitely integers $c$ for which the quadratic $x^2+2x+c$ qualifies. For example, for $a=1,b=2$, besides $c=-8$, the following values of $c$ also work:$\;1,0,-3,-15,-24,-35,-48,-63,-80 -99$, as well as infinitely many others. If instead you choose $a,r,s$ as described in my answer, you get all possible quadratics with integer coefficients satisfying the specified conditions.